# HTML Javascript displaying Japanese characters incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

My HTML

```
<head >
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

---

```
<div id="Target">食べる</div>
```

This displays perfectly fine .

```
document.getElementById("Target").innerHTML = "会う";
```

But once I use javascript to change the value of "Target" I get ��.

I'm fairly inexperienced when it comes to both javascript and encodings, so I apologize in advance if this is an easy fix.

Comment: have you saved the html/js file with the encoding set to utf8?

Comment: Would you prefer to share the browser/OS version. I tried it in Chrome/Mac, Firefox/Mac. Could not reproduce.

Comment: The ``text '食べる'`` within the ``div`` and the ``string '会う'`` in the ``js`` are not the same. Though it is not the cause for the problem stated.

Comment: You need to show a complete example that actually reproduces the issue. In particular, it seems that the JavaScript code is in a different file than the HTML document, linked with it with a `link` element. What is the encoding of this JavaScript file and how is its encoding declared?